# How to cancel api calls and close action channel in redux-saga flow?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a root flow that launches delayed flow `startBackgroundFlow`  .

```
function* rootSaga() {
 let task = null;
 while(true) {
  if(task) {
   cancel(task);
  }
  const data = yield take("START");
  task = yield fork(startBackgroundFlow, data);
  yield take(['STOP']);
  yield cancel(task);
 }
}
```

`startBackgroundFlow` just dispatch action "REQUEST";

```
function* startBackgroundFlow() {
 try {
  yield put("REQUEST");
  yield delay(1000);
 } catch() {
 } finally {
  if (yield cancelled()) {
   alert("cancelled")
  }
 }
}
```

Then I create action channel for buffering and data saving because of frequent api calls etc.

```
function* watchRequests() {
  // 1- Create a channel for request actions
  const requestChan = yield actionChannel('REQUEST')
  while (true) {
    // 2- take from the channel
    const {payload} = yield take(requestChan)
    // 3- Note that we're using a blocking call
    yield call(handleRequest, payload)
  }
}
```

It's works fine, but I don't know, how I can cancel api calls and close requestChan by `"STOP"` action like in `rootSaga`

Answer (score 0):

I found how I can clear channel and cancel api calls

```
function* watchRequests() {
  // 1- Create a channel for request actions
  const requestChan = yield actionChannel('REQUEST')
   while (true) {
    // 2. Pop request from the channel
    const action = yield take(requestChan)

    const { task, cancel } = yield race({
      task: call(handleRequest, action),
      cancel: take("STOP")
    })

    if(cancel !== undefined) {
      yield flush(requestChan)
    }
  }
}
```